# No paint profiler in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use the Chrome devtools timeline to improve animation performances, but I can't find the `Paint Profiler`. I recorded some seconds of an animation and then clicked on a paint event in the timeline, as described here, basically: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool#profile-painting

But I don't see any `Paint Profiler` tab.

Here's how I see the console window:

[image]

I'm using Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit), on a Mac

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Updated Sept 2022 - Chrome Version 105.0.5195.125 (Official Build) (arm64)**

This feature does still exist however it is no longer present in the performance section. Instead it can be found in the Layers tab.

[image: Instructions on how to access chrome paint profiler]

[image: Paint Profiler at last]

**Updated at 2021 April**

The feature is still exist confirmed in Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (arm64)

[image]

**Updated at 20180806**

It becomes even harder to find in Version 68.0.3440.84 (Official Build) (64-bit). Follow the steps below to find the paint profiler in Google Chrome development tool.

1. Enable "Advanced paint instrumentation (slow)"

[image]

2. Record a timeline
3. Find a paint block and click on that block

[image]

4. Click the "Paint Profiler" inside **Preview** section

[image]

5. Here is the "Paint Profiler" you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Using Chromium 72, I don't have the red button from your first screenshot. There's the Screenshots checkbox, the Memory checkbox and then the Collect garbage button. Do you know if they removed this feature, or...?

Comment: Update the steps to get the profiler and confirmed it is still there.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to keep refreshing the page. Once the page loaded and Profile Paint pane does not appear you simply Ctrl+f and type paint and it's gonna show up. Depending on you computer hardware it takes few seconds before finally paint record loaded even if you look it up(Ctrl+f). Wait a few seconds and then look up for paint, you don't need to refresh!