# Where is the paint profiler in the new Performance tab of Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have already seen the paint profiler in the preview pane under the Timeline tab of Chrome dev tools. Now Chrome has updated the Timeline tab to performance tab, I couldn't find the paint profiler. I have already checked the summary pane and the preview pane.

I have attached a screenshot after clicking a paint event. In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437722/no-paint-profiler-in-chrome-devtools) asked in stack overflow, the answer was to look in the preview pane. The paint profiler does not appear in the preview pane nor in the summary.
Also the answer in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437722/no-paint-profiler-in-chrome-devtools) was specific to previous version of dev tools corresponding to the timeline tab and not the updated performance tab.

[Screenshot after clicking a paint event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0IP7.jpg)

[Screenshot of summary tab after clicking a paint event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVeNm.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No paint profiler in Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437722/no-paint-profiler-in-chrome-devtools) - use the [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43039695).

Comment: I have edited the question and **explained why my question wouldn't be a possible duplicate**. I have also **attached a screenshot** after clicking a paint event.

Comment: It's not a paint **event**. Click it in the flame chart as shown in the linked answer.

Comment: The linked topic has two answer, look at the 2nd answer: https://puu.sh/wEtXN/c0216569e3.png

Comment: Follow the steps precisely. Enable the corresponding option: "Advanced paint instrumentation" and redo the recording.

Comment: Yeah, I clicked a paint in the flame chart, here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVeNm.jpg) of the summary tab.

Comment: Yeah got it! Didn't enable "Advanced paint instrumentation" before.