# No preview tab with paint profiler in chrome beta devtools & no summary tab in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have already tried this one:
[No paint profiler in Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437722/no-paint-profiler-in-chrome-devtools)

[This is how it's appearing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMA7S.png)

Preview & link for paint profiler is not visible. I have tried this in Chrome beta. In Chrome, even summary tab is not visible. How to get them?